# Pyqt5 loads dynamically without code prompting

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I use PyQt5 to design a GUI and I load it dynamically using `PyQt5.uic.loadui()`method.But in this way code prompt do not operate(have installed qt5-stubs). Is it normal?I mean I have to remember those objects' name, kind of laborious.
following is part of my code.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, \
    QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox,QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic


class LoginWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.registerwindow = RegisterWindow()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("login.ui")
    def lineedit_init(self):
        self.user_line.textchanged.connect(self.check_input_func)
        self.password_line.textchanged.connect(self.check_input_func)

    def pushbutton_init(self):
        self.loginButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.registerButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.loginButton.clicked.connect(self.check_login_func)
        self.registerButton.clicked.connect(self.open_register_window)
    def check_login_func(self):


    def check_input_func(self):
        if self.user_line.tetx() and self.password_line.text():
            self.loginButton.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.loginButton.setEnabled(False)


    def open_register_window(self):
        self.registerwindow = RegisterWindow()

        self.registerwindow.ui.exec_()


class RegisterWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("reg.ui")
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click_reg)

    def click_reg(self):

        QMessageBox.information(self, '12', '34', QMessageBox.Yes)
        self.ui.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = LoginWindow()
    login.ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

any solution will be helpful

Comment: I've worked with Ui having thousands of widgets without the need of completion, and only by wisely choosing verbose and intuitive names for widgets. Besides, nothing stops you to keep the Designer window open to check for them when in doubt. That said, afaik, there's no way to provide completion with `loadUi`, since that function does a lot of complex dynamic calls (including creating actual *code*, if I recall correctly). I know that there are some workarounds, but only for pyuic generated classes, but I wouldn't switch to them just for this reason.

Comment: On an unrelated note, your code has some issues; first of all, always try to provide a *valid* [mre], and just leave out parts that are not relevant for the question (like functions that are never called or are just left empty). Also, your usage of uic is wrong: you're creating subclasses that you're not actually using, since you always work with `self.ui`, which doesn't make a lot of sense. Add the `self` argument to `loadUi`, completely remove the assignment to `self.ui`, and you'll access everything as member of `self`, including the *actual* window subclass.

Comment: thanks! Actually I do not familiar with `oop`coding style so your advice would be helpful.